# Entity Framework Include call fails to get child objects

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

1->N Relationships are as follows.

Section -> Tables

Table -> Rounds

Round -> Bids

In a WebAPI Controller, I pass in a POSTed Bid Object, and it is saved perfectly (and even passed back to the client after saving so I am assuming this is not an issue).

Later though, in another controller, I try to retrieve a Round object and it's associated N Bids as follows:

```
var query = db.Rounds.Where(r => r.SectionId == section &&
        r.Number == roundId &&
        r.TableNumber == table)
        .Include(r => r.Section)
        .Include(r => r.Table)
        .Include(r => r.Bids);
```

I successfully get the Round object, as well as it's associated Table and Section references but no matter what I do, I get no Bid objects, even as I can see the successful save earlier, and see it in the database using VS.

I know there is some weirdness involving the way Include directives show up in the SQL, but nothing i've tried works.

The relevant part of the Bid Object follows (yes, the naming scheme is horrid -- long story):

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Column("Section", Order = 1)]
[ForeignKey("Round")]
public int SectionId { get; set; }

[Column("Table", Order = 2)]
[ForeignKey("Round")]
public int TableNumber { get; set; }

[Column("RoundNumber", Order = 3)]
[ForeignKey("Round")]
public int RoundNumber { get; set; }

public virtual Round Round { get; set; }
```

Round class follows

```
    [Key, Column("Section", Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SectionId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Table", Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int TableNumber { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Column("RoundNumber", Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableNumber")]
    public virtual Table Table { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of `Round` class as well?

Comment: Done. I've played with making the Bids collection in the Round object virtual and not, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm okay with requiring explicit loading, but again, when I use Include (or even Load(), I still don't get the Bids retrieved.

Comment: I've tried your model in clean EF6.1.3 context (it didn't accept `[ForeignKey("Section")]` so I had to change it to `[ForeignKey("SectionId")]`) and all I can do is to confirm that it works as expected (loads the related `Bids`).

Comment: Thank you Ivan. The problem turned out to be unrelated after all, but I would not have found it without you confirming this wasn't the problem area.